# Renicing X server and compositing manager (kwin-like) on a linux_kernel desktop

Tags: linux-kernel, xorg, scheduling, nice, kwin

- Long time ago (pre-2.6 kernels) on a very low end desktop, I had been happily following [Con Kolivas suggestion to (quite heavily (-10)) renice the X server.](https://lists.linuxcoding.com/kernel/2007-q2/msg04498.html) (for better responsiveness)
- With newer kernels, newer scheduler and smp systems, many had reported that even a 1 + or - variation in the default nice value was "*leading the rest of the system to suffer in quite obvious ways*". I went back to default.
- Having no longer paid any attention to this, I recently got the surprise to discover /usr/bin/X (1.20.8) launched *-nolisten tcp -keeptty :0 -auth blahblah* running with a nice value of -1. (*1)

---

**Q1 :** Is this (running the X server with a nice value of -1) nowadays considered the best option for a desktop mainly running SCHED_OTHER tasks under default nice value ?
Note *1 below would, in some very curious way indicate that, if not the best option, it is a deliberate will from freedesktop irrespective of any context (clients, hardware, kernel, cpu pinning…)

**Q2 :** Considering that I am also running a window/compositing manager (kwin_x11) said achieving most of the job the X-server used to achieve, should I consider consequent to also renice it ? in a greater or lesser amount that the X-server ? (X consumes on average 1,5 cpu time kwin_x11 does) (*2)

**Q3 :** Would it be pertinent to base the nice relative values of X / kwin_x11 on the relative values of their unvoluntary context switches ? (kwin_x11 gets (during some of my typical desktop workload) about 30 times more unvoluntary context switches than X)

---

**Q4 :** More generally speaking, in a client/server SCHED_OTHER world, is there a rule of thumb regarding relative nice values  between servers and clients apps ? And, considering this particular case (of X server/ X client), can I assume that the client will, most of the time, be waiting for the server's availability ?
Can I also assume that the worst consequence of kwin_X11 not receiving enough cpu time is frame dropping and consequently that having some X client capable to output X fps on a regular basis and kwin_X11 dropping a couple of frames from time to time would be just absurd ?

---

Figures when running some typical desktop workload for 5 minutes:

X (nice -1) ucs : 1525 / kwin ucs (nice  0) 51834 (GT=53359)
X (nice -1) ucs : 6337 / kwin ucs (nice -2) 38415 (GT=44752)

---

***1 :** From what I understand in [xinit](https://github.com/freedesktop/xorg-xinit/blob/master/xinit.c) code, xinit (parent) is responsible for that (`setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, serverpid, -1); as part of the startserver procedure) right after forking the child that will later exec the server...
In fact… right after… the following comment : ***don't nice server*** ??? which indeed increases even more my perplexity.

***2 :** I know that [Ananicy](https://github.com/Nefelim4ag/Ananicy) would heavily renice (-10) kwin if not even preferring some real time scheduling model (which I do not consider sensible (*3)). There is unfortunately no rationale given for this tuning and the corresponding rule is quite old (2018), a big amount of changes have been commited to kwin since.

***3 :** At least as far as kwin_X11 is concerned since, if my understanding is correct, the X server is still managing inputs.

Comment: From daily usage, did you experience any unresponsiveness with your current settings? Why don't you just play around with different nice values and see what happens? It's a pretty complex interaction, and probably depends heavily on the actual system, the timings on that system, and the usual system usage. I doubt any general answer is possible. Otherwise I'd apply the maxim "don't fix it if it's not broken".

Comment: @dirkt : I acknowledge that the major problem I face is… in my understanding. (I assume that the worse I would face if kwin does not get enough cpu time is a couple of frames being dropped from time to time, I'm not sure I would notice. BTW is this assumption right ?). I would have happily accepted that everything is heavily system dependent until I read init forking the server nice -1 irrespective of any consideration on the system.  And of course, Q3 is meant irrespective of the system & context.

Comment: @dirkt : Adding to that the fact that I do frequently experiment/enjoy the merits of "if it works don't fix it". However, I always need objective measures to tell me that it actually & objectively works. Desktop responsiveness is nothing but a perception (possibly depending on the age of the captain & his preferred beverages… ;-) )… Its similar to spend a week heating the planet recompiling all your softwares -funroll-loops and be convinced that there has been a noticeable improvement… ;-)